# Required Help in adding data labels to histogram - d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here's the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fJGaZ/1/).

I've created a responsive `histogram`.

And I wanted to add the data labels to it.

I tried with this code. But it didn't help me out.

```
svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(histogram)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
        .text(function(d) { return d; })
```

Please help me in solving this.

I guess I'm doing it all right.

But I don't know why the text elements aren't created yet.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 small problems with your code:

- The `.selectAll("text")` selects the `text` elements that were added for the axes, matches the given data against them and your `.enter()` selection is empty. Hence no new text is added. You can fix this by e.g. assigning a distinguishing class to the text labels.
- The y position should be `height - y(d.y)`.
- You probably don't want to show the entire object as a label, but just `d.y`.

The following code addresses these issues.

```
svg.selectAll("text.label")
        .data(histogram)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); })
        .text(function(d) { return d.y; })
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fJGaZ/2/).

Comment: Thanks for the briefing. I also wanted to add line corresponding to some value. Suppose think as 240. So if I give flat 240. It's moving 240 pixels. And if i give `y(240)` it's giving me some value. If i give `x(240)`. It says me `x` is not defined. Please help me?

Comment: You'll have to give me some more context here. I may be better to post this as a separate question.

Comment: Here's the [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831098/drawing-a-line-on-a-histogram-d3/22831557?nodirect=1#22831557).