# drawing a line on a histogram - d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a histogram using `d3`.

Everything was fine and here's where I got stuck.

I wanted to draw a vertical line on some value.

Think that I wanted to draw a line corresponding to some value. Suppose 180.

I tried, tried and still trying I can't figure a way to do it.

Here's the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fJGaZ/3/).

Someone please help me to draw a line corresponding to some specific value.

Comment: With the scale you have, you can draw vertical lines only at the positions of the bars. If you want to be able to draw lines in between, you need a linear instead of an ordinal scale.

Comment: The chart is responsive. If the change ordinal to linear. Will it still be responsive?

Comment: Well in principle yes. It will be more difficult to make a histogram though. You may want to use two separate scales (ordinal for the histogram and linear for the lines).

Comment: Great.... If I wanted to add a line on the bar using the same ordinal then how will I do it?

Comment: Just pass the same x coordinate you're using for the bar.

Comment: I wanted to add only one line. And I'm passing it like this `.attr("x1", x(240))`. And the result is 0. Like stays at the beginning of the chart itself. I've tried it and update the fiddle too. Please check that once.

Comment: You need to use *exactly* the same value as for the bars, e.g. 165 -- http://jsfiddle.net/fJGaZ/5/

Comment: It's not possible to draw in the middle of bars?

Comment: You have to offset it by half the range band of the scale for that.

Comment: How can I do it? I can't add the remaining value to it. If I do so. The result will be 0 for "x1".

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/fJGaZ/6/

Comment: How I can get those bar values dynamically. Coz I'm updating the histogram through AJAX. And every time the value will not be fixed. Any suggestions on getting those value dynamically?

Comment: It's all in your data -- just get the values from there.

Comment: How can I do it? How can I always target the nearest value close to it?

Comment: Ok, where do you want to draw lines? At all the value positions? Do you want a kind of grid?

Comment: I wanted to draw a single vertical line corresponding to the value 160. This value is fixed but the histogram bins and ticks will not be fixed as the data keeps on changing on dropdown change.

Comment: As I've said, you need a different kind of scale for that.

Comment: If I use `linear` scale. Can I use `rangeRoundBands()` in the x variable?

Comment: No. A linear scale doesn't have that method.

Comment: Then I guess so it's not possible to do it with the current scale. If I wanted to add the line. Chart will not be responsive. If I want the chart to be responsive. I can't add the line.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone interested to know how to draw vertical lines, below is the code on how to draw vertical line. Edited from the Fiddle provided by OP.

```
var svg = d3.select(reference).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height + 20);
// to draw lines at x=6 and x=500
svg.append("g").selectAll("line")
    .data([
        { y1: y(0), y2: height, x1: 6, x2: 6 },
        { y1: y(0), y2: height, x1: 500, x2: 500 }
    ])
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "specification-line")
    .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.y1; })
    .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.y2; })
    .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.x1; })
    .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.x2; });
```

Styling a bit with dashes and red color line

```
.specification-line { fill:none; stroke: #ff0000; stroke-opacity: .6; stroke-width: 1px; shape-rendering: auto; }
```